# Bash: Save and print arguments from an array

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

How do you save all the arguments in a bash script to an array and print them individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialize the array:

```
ARGS=("$@")              # "$@" gives the arguments passed to the script
ARGS=(arg1 arg2 arg3)    # or fill the array out yourself
```

Display the array items:

```
for ARG in "${ARGS[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$ARG"
done
```

Comment: +1. Can also use a C-like for loop to iterate over the indices: `for (( i=0; i < ${#ARGS[@]}; i++ )); do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${ARGS[i]}"; done`